# Can I send the text from tag select of html to database

Tags: html, html-select

I'm download library about all address dependent dropdown list of my country. 
but the problem is when I $_POST this and insert to database (MySQL), database have show id of district (value of `<select>`)  not name of district(Tokyo).  How should I do?

```
<tr>
      <td>เขต/อำเภอ :</td>
      <td><select value="district_id" name="district"> Tokyo </select></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: learn about selection tag. here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0):

Give to $_POST the right name. For example $_POST('name') instead of $_POST('id')